# Excel vba to remove "?" (question mark) and "*" (star)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace all special characters in an Excel sheet.

But `?` (question mark) and `*` (asterisk) are resulting in a blank cell

The code I'm using:

```
Selection.Replace What:="!", Replacement:=" "
Selection.Replace What:="@", Replacement:=" "
Selection.Replace What:="#", Replacement:=" "
```

.... so on

Comment: I don't understand. Your title says you want to remove them. But your example replaces them with a space. Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: yup.. i need to remove them but with spaces :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question marks and asterisks are known as wildcards in find and replace functions, this means they already mean something other than their string values. In order to get round this you need to precede them with a tilde (~).

Try:

```
Selection.Replace What:="~?", Replacement:=" "
Selection.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:=" "
```

Here's a helpful link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/214138

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions: http://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/

It's a much more versatile way to do text-matching anyway.

Comment: have you used help option of regex-addin in excel...???
make sure you are alone when checking....